# Best way to store password in web and AngularJS 1.5?

Tags: angularjs, passwords

I need to store the login and password to re-login to an API as the session expires every hour or so. I am only using AngularJS. Can anyone please recommend the best practices to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [JWT](https://jwt.io/).

And you can store your token in a browser storage of your choice, which I recommend [LocalForage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) with any persistent storage using its custom driver.